# Random Characters Appearing When Printing Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm relatively new to coding array functions in C. After numerous tries, I've decided to surrender and ask for help.

I wish to the user to input the words and store them into the 2d array words. The problem is that it prints the words but also prints out random characters.

```
#include "mp1_lib.h"

void get_words(int n, char words[][16])
{       
    char c = ' ';
    char check;

    for(int x=0; x <= n; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
            {                   
                c = getchar();
                check = c;

                if (check == '\n')
                    {    
                        break;    
                    } 

                words[x][y] = c;                        
            }    
        }           
}             

void print_words(int n, char words[][16]) 
{
    for(int x=1; x <= n; x++)
    {   
        for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
        {   
                if (words[x][y] == '\n')
                {
                    break;
                } 

                putchar(words[x][y]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

Comment: did u really mean x to go from 1..n? Perhaps it needs to be 0..(n-1)? y seems to be, um, better.

Comment: `for(int x=0; x <= n; x++)`, arrays are indexed `0 -> n-1` in C so `x < n` is the proper test.

Comment: Hi! I've tried that but it doesn't print out anything. Making n ---> n += 1; works though.

Comment: Unless you *nul-terminate* each word in the array, you will have to store the length of each word or otherwise provide a *sentinel* so you know when to stop printing.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a *string* is an array of characters with the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` as the character that marks the end of the contents of the string within the array. That is how all *string* functions like `strlen` or `printf` using the `'%s'` *format specifier* to print a string -- know where the string stops.

If you do not *nul-terminate* the array of characters -- then it is not a string, it is simply an array and you cannot pass an un-terminate array to any function expecting a string - or it won't know where the string ends (and in the case of `printf` will just print whatever unspecified character happens to be in memory until it comes upon a `'\0'` to stop the output (or SegFaults).

If you don't *nul-terminate* the words in your array, then you will have to have some way to store the number of characters in each word, so your print function will know where to stop printing. (if you have a two-letter word like `"Hi"` in a 16-char array, you can only print 2 characters from the array. Especially if it is an *uninitialized* array, then you will simply get gibberish printed for characters `3-16`.

Your second problem is -- "How do you know how many words you have stored in your array?" -- you don't return a value from `getwords`, so unless you change the function type to `int` and return the number of words that you stored in your array, your only other option is to pass a pointer to an integer and update the value at that address so the value is available back in the calling function. Either way is fine, you generally only worry about making a value available through a pointer if you are already returning another value and need a second method to make another updated value visible back in the calling function (`main()` here).

Putting those pieces together, and passing a pointer to the number of words to `getwords` to make the number of words entered available back in `main()` (so you know how many words `print_words` has to print), you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 16     /* if you need constants, define them */
#define MAXW 32

void getwords (char (*words)[MAXC], int *n)
{
    int col = 0;                        /* column count */
    while (*n < MAXW) {                 /* while words < MAXW */
        int c = getchar();              /* read char */
        /* column reaches MAXC-1 or if whitespace or EOF */
        if (col == MAXC - 1 || isspace(c) || c == EOF) {
            if (col) {                  /* if col > 0 */
                words[(*n)++][col] = 0; /* nul-terminate, increment n */
                col = 0;                /* set col to zero */
            }
            if (c == EOF)               /* if char EOF - all done */
                return;
        }
        else    /* otherwise - just add char to word */
            words[*n][col++] = c;
    }
}

void prnwords (char (*words)[MAXC], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* loop over each of n-words & print */
        printf ("words[%2d]: %s\n", i, words[i]);
}

int main (void) {

    char words[MAXW][MAXC] = {""};  /* intiliaze words all zero */
    int nwords = 0;                 /* number of words zero */

    getwords (words, &nwords);
    prnwords (words, nwords);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** when reading characters into the `words` array, you must check the number of character read again the maximum characters per-word (`MAXC`) and the number of words against the maximum number of words/rows in your array (`MAXW`) to prevent writing outside of your array bounds -- which will invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your program)

(**note:** the `ctype.h` header was included to simplify checking whether the character read was *whitespace* (e.g. a `space`, `tab`, or `newline`). If you can't use it, then simply use an `if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')` instead.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog has fleas and my cat has none" | ./bin/getwords
words[ 0]: my
words[ 1]: dog
words[ 2]: has
words[ 3]: fleas
words[ 4]: and
words[ 5]: my
words[ 6]: cat
words[ 7]: has
words[ 8]: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with c. But it appears like you are not addding the new line character to the words array in `get_words`.

```
check = c;

if (check == '\n')
{

    break;

} 

words[x][y] = c;
```

So when printing in `print_words` this will never be true.

```
if (words[x][y] == '\n')
{
    break;
}
```

That means that whatever happens to be in the memory location is what will get printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your words have neither the newline character (which makes your code print garbage) nor the terminating NULLs (which makes them illegal as C strings). At least add `words[x][y]="\n"` before breaking the inner loop. Or, rather, move the `if` check after the assignment `words[x][y]=c;`. And yes, the loop should go from 0 to `n-1`.

As a side note, you do not need the variable `check`: just use `c`.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to assign space as a placeholder for the 15 characters and it worked. Thanks, everyone! :)

```
#include "mp1_lib.h"


void get_words(int n, char words[][16])
{

    char c = ' ';
    char check;


    for(int x=0; x < n; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
            {   
                words[x][y] = ' ';

            }

        }


    for(int x=0; x < n; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
            {   

                c = getchar();
                check = c;

                if (check == '\n')
                    {
                        break;
                    } 
                words[x][y] = c;
            }

        }


} 




void print_words(int n, char words[][16]) 
{

    for(int x=0; x < n; x++)
    {   
        for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
        {   

                putchar(words[x][y]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is still undefined behavior. If it works, it is only by chance.

Comment: Hi! can you elaborate more on this please? :)